# How can decidability/semi-decidability/undecidability have impact on REAL life applications/examples?

Tags: undecidability, semi-decidability, decidability

How decidability/semi-decidability/undecidability has impact on REAL life applications/examples? I understand that it can be used for implementation of various algorithms but what else?

Comment: On the one hand, i think this question is way too broad. On the other hand, I also do not understand it. Can you clarify how undecidability results can be used to implement algorithms?

Comment: mostly, if something you want to do is undecidable, then you give up